# converting raster to vector using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, interpolation

I am trying to convert multiple raster (name of raste: 01_sr, 002_sr....012_sr) to vector through loop function and output of vestor name wil same as of input. but loop function is not working. can anyone guide me on this subject, how to fix this error?

```
Error Massage: 
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    <module1>   15      
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RasterToPoint_Conversion'
```

Code:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = "D:\SOLAR-RADIATION-NOAA"
outpoint = r"D:\SOLAR-RADIATION-NOAA"
field = "VALUE"
Rasters = arcpy.ListRasters ()
for inRaster in Rasters:

     outpoint1 = r"D:\SOLAR-RADIATION-NOAA\\"+ "inRaster"

     arcpy.RasterToPoint_Conversion(inRaster, outpoint1, field)
```

Updated code, still error exist

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = "D:\SOLAR-RADIATION-NOAA"
outpoint = r"D:\SOLAR-RADIATION-NOAA"
field = "VALUE"
Rasters = arcpy.ListRasters ()
for inRaster in Rasters:

     outpoint1 = r"outpoint"+ "inRaster"

     arcpy.RasterToPoint_Conversion(inRaster1, outpoint, field)
```

Edited Code , Error still not solved

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = "D:\SOLAR-RADIATION-NOAA"
outpoint = r"D:\SOLAR-RADIATION-NOAA"
field = "VALUE"
Rasters = arcpy.ListRasters ()
for inRaster in Rasters:

     outpoint1 = outpoint+ inRaster
     arcpy.AddMessage(inRaster)

     arcpy.RasterToPoint_Conversion(inRaster, outpoint1, field)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is case sensitive, therefore, `RasterToPoint_Conversion` needs to be replaced with `RasterToPoint_conversion`

Your other problem is that you are trying to append the raster name with an extension to the output path. I would recommend becoming familiar with path manipulation using `os.path.join()`. In this example, I isolate (split) the raster iterable name from the extension using `ras.split(".")[0]`.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

inws = r"D:\SOLAR-RADIATION-NOAA"
outws = r"D:\SOLAR-RADIATION-NOAA\output_workspace" # Note the new output directory here

arcpy.env.workspace = inws
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

for ras in rasters:
     outpoint = os.path.join(outws, ras.split(".")[0] + ".shp")
     arcpy.RasterToPoint_Conversion(ras, outpoint, "VALUE")
```

Comment: Thank you. I ran the code suggested by you. But i am getting the following error massage Message `File Name Line Position 
Traceback    
    <module> <module2> 14  
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RasterToPoint_Conversion`

Comment: I've updated the post to include the problem. Essentially, Python is case sensitive and the `RasterToPoint_Conversion` function needs to be converted to `RasterToPoint_conversion`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Aaron Code now successfully running.

Comment: I have one more problem regarding name of output during conversion of NetCDF to raster, which code now i am using that giving the same output name as input , but i want to write output name like 001_sr, 002_sr..012_sr. Once i upload that issue but not received  any suggestion yet. Can i upload it once again now ??

Comment: You can start a counter to do naming like that. Before the `for` loop, add `counter = 1`. At the bottom of the `for` loop add `counter += 1`. Then simply add a variable in your `for` loop like: name = `"00%_sr.tif" % counter`. Insert that variable into your output path like so: `os.path.join(outws, name)`.

Comment: Thank you. I am not talking about this code which we have just solved. I am talking my another one more program NetCDF to RASTER conversion

Comment: I just uploading it as new question. My humble request kindly guide me to solve the issue

Comment: I just added one new question which i have already told you. Kindly help me to solve this issue

Comment: Nice code Aaron. @ShouvikJha : as I said in my answer, you should always check your code with debugging techniques, like controlling your variables and set breakpoints. It's very useful to resolve variable types issues. Don't worry, the more you code, the more you'll get used to the typical errors one usually makes (like forgetting ":" or bad indentation).